# Scrolling Horizontally on Windows 10 Laptop Touchpad stopped working after update to Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, scroll, windows-10, eclipse-neon, touchpad

I am running Eclipse Neon on Windows 10 and I'm pretty sure I was always able to scroll up, down, left, and right using my laptop's touchpad with two fingers. After updating to Eclipse Neon, I can't scroll horizontally with my touchpad and have to manually drag the scrollbar left and right, which is very annoying. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @AhmedHamdy switched to Mac 

Comment: so this is our only solution now! 

Comment: @AhmedHamdy one of our solutions at least 